# Is it possible to pass text from edittext to webview?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am building an Android app in `WebView` for a forum. I want to make a custom login screen, but is it possible to pass login credentials from an `EditText` to `WebView` and then log into the forum? The HTML code below is the login part from the forum.

```html
<form class="header-login" method="post" action="/forum/handle-login/">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">

  <input type="submit" value="Inloggen">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one of the way is by using java script just find id the element by and set the value what you want to set to the input box

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        webview.evaluateJavascript(script, 
            new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String result) {
                }
            });
    else
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:"+script);
```

this is how you can set the value using JS

```
var form = document.getElementById("formID");

var textField = formElement.elements["Input Text Id"];

textField.value = 'yourValue';
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was messing around with your code, but I don't know how and where to use the javascript code.

Comment: @DevEloper have you done it? suppose we have a url of webview. that webiew has a edit text field and a submit button, can we perfom action to enter text and press action by android app to webview.I mean without client the webview submit button , it should auto click by mobile app. can we do that?

Comment: @DevEloper any update on this? Do let me know if it was done

Answer (score -1):

```
<form class="header-login" method="post" action="/forum/handle-login/">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">

  <input type="submit" value="Inloggen">
</form>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("username").value = "Johnny Bravo";
}
```

```html
  <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```